# PyQt4,QTableWidget: Prevent row to be sorted when horizontal header is clicked

Tags: pyqt4

My table is a QTableWidget I have on it an empty row.
When a horizontal header is clicked I don't want this particular row to be sorted with the others rows. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using a `QTableWidget`. If you really want this you must replace your `QTableWidget` by a `QTableView` and connect that to your own model class (that inherits from a `QTableModel`). I you got this working you can insert a `QSortFilterProxyModel` in between the model and the view. This gives you full control over the sorting. The concepts are all explained in the [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) chapter of the Qt documentation.

This is indeed some work, you have to decide if it's worth the effort.